# infinite loop in shared memory

Tags: c, shared-memory

Within a Ubuntu virtal machine, I have created two c programs called "server" and "client". When I run server with an input (some integer) and then run client afterwards, client will output the integer that I gave to server. This is working with shared memory. My problem is, after client receives the info, it sets a variable to "CONSUMED", and server has a loop that waits for that to happen, but it never seems to work correctly. This all works if I remove the loop altogether, but I need it in there to be able to ensure that client receives the integer and I don't just continue without it happening.

Here is my code for server.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include "shm.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

   int retVal = 0;
   ShmData *addr;  

   if(argc != 2){
      printf("please enter 1 argument.\n");
      return 0;
   }

   int fd = shm_open("shm.h", O_CREAT | O_RDWR , 0666);
   if(fd == -1){
      printf("!!!error with shm_open.\n");
   }

   if(ftruncate(fd, sizeof(ShmData)) == -1){        
      printf("!!!error with ftruncate.\n");
   }

   addr = mmap(0, sizeof(ShmData), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);

   if(addr == MAP_FAILED){
      printf("!!!error with mmap.\n");
   }

   addr->status = INVALID;
   addr->data = atoi(argv[1]);
   addr->status = VALID;

   printf("[Server]: Server data Valid... waiting for client\n");

   while(addr->status != CONSUMED){
      sleep(1);                        //THIS LOOP NEVER EXITS
   }

   printf("[Server]: Server Data consumed!\n");

   munmap(addr, 0);         
   if(close(fd) == -1){ 
      printf("!!!error with close.\n");
   }
   shm_unlink("smh.h");

   printf("[Server]: Server exiting...\n\n\n");


   return(retVal);

}
```

Here is my code for client.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include "shm.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

   int retVal = 0;

   int fd = shm_open("shm.h", O_CREAT | O_RDWR , 0666);
   if(fd == -1){
      printf("!!!error with shm_open.\n");
   }

   ShmData *addr;  
   addr = mmap(0, sizeof(ShmData), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);

   printf("[Client]: Waiting for valid data ...\n");

   while(addr->status != VALID){
      sleep(1); 
   }

   printf("[Client]: Received %d\n", addr->data);

   addr->status = CONSUMED;

   munmap(addr, 0);         

   printf("[Client]: Client exiting...\n");

   return(retVal);

}
```

And here is the shm.h file:

```
enum StatusEnum{INVALID, VALID, CONSUMED};

typedef struct{
   enum StatusEnum status;
   int data;
}ShmData;
```

I've been banging my head against the computer screen for a long time but I still don't see anything wrong with my code. How can I get this loop to succeed and exit?

Comment: My first thought is whether the compiler is doing an optimization for you. The `volatile` keyword is a hint to the compiler that a variable or memory area may change so you may need `volatile ShmData *addr;`

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem. The code works fine for me. Are both files compiled with the same compiler and options?

Comment: @Marian yup, I did "gcc -o server server.c -lrt" and "gcc -o client client.c -lrt". It seems to be something wrong with my virtual machine. I emailed my code to a friend and, like you, the program worked on his machine.

Comment: The fact that you are using a virtual machine is what most people would consider vital information. Please update your post with this and any other environmental information.